# Flask-Mongoengine custom order-by comparator

Tags: python-3.x, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I am using `Flask-Mongoengine` as an ORM for my flask application. I define a `Document` to store unique versions in a string:

```
MyDocument(db.Document):
    version = db.StringField(primary_key=True, required=True)
```

The value stored in the `StringField` is in the following format:

```
a.b.c.d
```

I run into issues when it comes to using `order_by` for my queries:

```
MyDocument.objects.order_by('version')
```

More precisely, if the first part of the version (`a` in the format example above) contains multiple digits, it doesn't sort properly (e.g: `15.20.142` < `1.7.9`). While I could obviously do something like:

```
tmp = Document.objects.all()
result = some_merge_sort(tmp)
```

However, that requires writing, testing and maintaining a sorting algorithm. This then brings me to my next solution, which is to overwrite the comparator used in `order_by`. The issue is, I'm not sure how to do this properly. Do I have to define a custom attribute type, or is there some hook I'm supposed to override?

In any case, I thought I would as the good folks on stackoverflow before I go into re-writing the wheel.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the detailed question. Could you also add a snippet of the code you have now, ideally that is easy to reproduce? That would help others to give you a tailored answers.

Comment: @NickShebanov I've added pertinent code snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some digging into the `Mongoengine` source code, I found out that it uses the `PyMongo` `cursor` `sort` which itself wraps the queries made to `MongoDB`. In other words, my `Document` definition is too high in the chain to even affect the `order_by` result.

As such, the solution I went with was to write a `classmethod`. This simply takes in a `mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet` instance and applies a sort on the `version` attribute.

```
from mongoengine.queryset import QuerySet
from packaging import version

class MyDocument(db.Document):
    version = db.StringField(primary_key=True, required=True)

    @classmethod
    def order_by_version(_, queryset, reverse=False):
        """
            Wrapper function to order a given queryset of this classes
            version attribute.

            :params:
                - `QuerySet` :queryset: - The queryset to order the elements.
                - `bool`     :reverse:  - If the results should be reversed.

            :raises:
                - `TypeError` if the instance of the given queryset is not a `QuerySet`.

            :returns:
                - `List` containing the elements sorted by the version attribute.
       """
       # Instance check the queryset.
       if not isinstance(queryset, QuerySet):
           raise TypeError("order_by_version requires a QuerySet instance!")

       # Sort by the version attribute.
       return sorted(queryset, key=lambda obj: version.parse(obj.version), reverse=reverse)
```

Then to utilize this method, I can simply do as follows:

```
MyDocument.order_by_version(MyDocument.objects)
```

As for my reason for taking the `QuerySet` instance rather than doing the query from within the classmethod, it was simply to allow the opportunity to call other `Mongoengine` methods prior to doing the ordering. Because I used `sorted`, it will maintain any existing order, so I can still use the built-in `order_by` for other attributes.